# Applescript: Merging lists into new lists

Tags: list, applescript

I am bumping up against what is probably an easy-fix problem as a relative Applescript noob. I have three lists of data which I want to re-organise. The first of the original lists contains ID numbers, the second names and the third a status. Example:

```
set listNumbers to {}
set listNumbers to {} & {4456, 3232, 6545, 789}
set listStatuses to {}
set listStatuses to {} & {"Eaten", "Beheaded", "Shot", "Lost"}
set listNames to {}
set listNames to {} & {"Jim", "Joe", "Steve", "Mike"}
```

I want to automatically extract / create x number of new lists, each with three items and following the pattern of item 1 from each list, item 2 from each list, etc. So I would get something like list1 = {4456, "Eaten", "Jim"}, list2 = {3232, "Beheaded", "Joe"}, etc. The original lists will actually be much longer, with several hundred items, and will be generated dynamically so I don't want to have manually code for every list.

I'm struggling to find useful examples to apply to this, but it seems like it should be straightforward! Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, of course it assumes that all lists contain the same number of items.
The result is in the variable `resultList`

```
set listNumbers to {4456, 3232, 6545, 789}
set listStatuses to {"Eaten", "Beheaded", "Shot", "Lost"}
set listNames to {"Jim", "Joe", "Steve", "Mike"}

set resultList to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count listNumbers
    set end of resultList to {item i of listNumbers, item i of listStatuses, item i of listNames}
end repeat
```

or you could get the result as a list of records `{name:<name>, status:<status>, number:<number>}`

```
...
repeat with i from 1 to count listNumbers
    set end of resultList to {|number|:item i of listNumbers, status:item i of listStatuses, |name|:item i of listNames}
end repeat
```

Comment: I would suggest to use records instead. it depends what you want to do with that list, but I guess you will need to know the status or the name of item  x. then it is much easier with records of attribute than with sequential list.

Comment: Excellent advice, thank you both. I had been considering using records for exactly the reason @pbell suggested; will be tackling this piece of work early next week so I'll let you know how it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you're suggesting, having hundreds of separate lists, is not going to be beneficial to you. I like to use "lists of lists". You would create is like so:

```
set listNumbers to {} & {4456, 3232, 6545, 789}
set listStatuses to {} & {"Eaten", "Beheaded", "Shot", "Lost"}
set listNames to {} & {"Jim", "Joe", "Steve", "Mike"}

set listOfLists to {}
repeat with n from 1 to (count listNumbers)
    set end of listOfLists to {item n of listNumbers, item n of listStatuses, item n of listNames}
end repeat
return listOfLists
-- {{4456, "Eaten", "Jim"}, {3232, "Beheaded", "Joe"}, {6545, "Shot", "Steve"}, {789, "Lost", "Mike"}}
```

This way, you can reference item 2 of item 2 of listOfLists, etc.